# Is issue grouping based on part of the message possible?

Tags: sentry

My log messages are of the form `"{title}: {details}"` and I would like to group issues by title.

Is there a way to add a fingerprint rule to my sentry project that does this?

I am reading this page:

- https://docs.sentry.io/product/data-management-settings/event-grouping/fingerprint-rules/

If I could capture the content of the glob stars and refer to the with `$i`, it would be something like this

```
message:"*:*" -> $1
```

- match messages that contain `:` and group by everything before the colon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible on the Sentry side. You need to apply that fingerprint on the SDK side if you require regexp-like matches.